# Change layout order on Tablet Devices using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the E & F divs above C div for tablet view of a page am working on but cant' seem find any solution that can help. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-container">
    <div style="border: 1px solid white;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">A</div>
    
    <div style="border: 1px solid white;" class="col-lg-6 col-md-7">B</div>
    
    <div style="border: 1px solid white;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">C</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid white;">D</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7" style="border: 1px solid white;">E</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid white;">F</div>
    
  </div>
  
  
<!--   <div class="row">
    <div style="border: 1px solid white;" class="col-6 col-sm-4">D</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid white;" class="col-6 col-sm-4">E</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid white;" class="col-6 col-sm-4">F</div>
  </div> -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row > div {
  padding: 10px;
}
 div {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/OluwaseunII/pen/rNemVyj

Comment: Can you confirm which Bootstrap breakpoint you mean by "tablet" (e.g. sm, or med) and the order you want - is it A B E F C D?

Comment: @FluffyKitten breakpoint md in this format
A B
E F
C
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`order-n`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order) Bootstrap classes to set the order of the cols whn you are using flex, starting with `order-0`. As with most Bootstrap grid classes, you can also specify the breakpoint e.g. `order-sm-0`

You can give col A and col B the classes `order-0` and `order-1` respectively. Then for the rest you need to specify 2 classes - one for the `md` breakpoint and one for the smaller screens.

So col C for example is `order-2 order-md-4` i.e. position 3 on screens up to 768px and position 5 for 768px and higher.

See the code below where I have rearranged the cols in the order A B E F C D at the md breakpoint:

```css
.container {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row > div {
  padding: 10px;
}
 div {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-container">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 order-0" style="border: 1px solid white;">A</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 order-1" style="border: 1px solid white;">B</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 order-4 order-md-2" style="border: 1px solid white;">C</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 order-5 order-md-3" style="border: 1px solid white;">D</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 order-2 order-md-4" style="border: 1px solid white;">E</div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 order-3 order-md-5" style="border: 1px solid white;">F</div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can I get something along this line?
```
A                 B
D                 E
C
F
```

Comment: @O'seunIyadi Yes, you just need to change the number in the `order-md-n` classes in the relevant cols to the positions you want - so D would be `order-md-2`, E: `order-md-3` C: `order-md-4` and F is just `order-5` because it is in the same position on all screens

Comment: You are a genius!
Thank YOU